# Initialize polymorphic C array with references/pointers to temporary statically allocated objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, polymorphism, temporary-objects

## Question

Is it possible to initialize a polymorphic C array <sub>(e.g. an array of type `ParentClass*`, containing pointers of type `Subclass1*`, `Subclass2*` etc.)</sub> with references/pointers to temporary objects in C++?
As all `temporary objects` are known at compile time, I don't want to use `unique_ptr` or anything with a dynamic allocation, e.g. using `new`.

## Use case

### Current version

Given

```cpp
class Command {
 public:
  virtual void run(const vector<string>& args) = 0;
};

class Generate: public Command {
 public:
  void run(const vector<string>& args) override;
};

class Scan: public Command {
 public:
  void run(const vector<string>& args) override;
};
```

I want to define a class `App` holding a `static Command* commands[]` data member, e.g.:

```cpp
// App.hpp
class App {
  static Command* commands[];
}

// App.cpp
Generate generate;
Scan scan;
Command* App::commands[] {&generate, &scan};
```

### Compiler errors

While trying to find a working solution, I encountered the following list of compiler errors:

```
taking the address of a temporary object of type 'Generate':
  Command* App::commands[] {&Generate()};`
```

```
non-const lvalue reference to type 'Generate' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Generate'
  Command* App::commands[] {&static_cast<Generate&>(Generate())};
```

```
cannot initialize an array element of type 'Command *' with an rvalue of type 'const Generate *'
  Command* App::commands[] {&static_cast<const Generate&>(Generate())};
```

Compiler: `g++: Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.29.1)`.

### Sought changes

In `App.cpp` it'd love to remove the global variables `generate` and `scan` and use temporary objects instead, something like:

```cpp
// App.cpp
Command* App::commands[] {&Generate(), &Scan()};
```

even better, get rid of `App.cpp` and define `commands` directly in `App.hpp`, e.g.:

```cpp
// App.hpp
class App {
  static Command* commands[] {&Generate(), &Scan};
}

// App.cpp is deleted
```

Comment: The reason they're called "temporary" is because they quickly disappear. As soon as the array is initialized they'll get destroyed. Even if this was possible, you'll be left with an array to pointers to destroyed objects, and using them in any way will immediately unleash a horde [of demons flying out of everyone's noses](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Do you like demons flying out of everyone's noses? Why? Nobody likes that.

Comment: Probably worth asking yourself whether these commands need to actually store any state at all. As currently written, the `run` method is non-const which implies the Command object can modify itself. The class design also implies some commands can inherit others, or that a Command object can be initialized with additional data. If none of this is relevant, you could greatly simplify things by turning your commands into lambdas instead... or even just plain functions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I get that. But temporaries are useful for initializing a lot of objects. `string` is very often initialized by a temporary object. I had hoped something equally nice would be possible in my case too.

Comment: @paddy In that particular case that is a good idea. Declaring `run` as a `static` I was able to get the same behavior using: `inline static void(*commands[])(const vector<string>&) {Generate::run};`. If any state were needed though, a solution would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not with pointers. It can work only with arrays to aggregate classes containing a reference member:

```
struct CommandRef {
    Command&& command;
};

/* DO NOT USE, SEE BELOW */

CommandRef App::commands[] {{Generate()}, {Scan()}};
```

However, I strongly advice against this, because the above relies on very particular lifetime extension rules for binding of references in aggregate initialization.

It can easily be made to have undefined behavior by mistake, especially if lacking understanding of the formal lifetime rules, for example by

- making `CommandRef` a non-aggregate class.
- using `(`/`)` instead of `{`/`}` in the aggregate-initialization.
- applying any operation between the prvalue expression from which the temporary is materialized and the binding of the reference.
- using any other container than built-in arrays or `std::array`.

Compilers have (at least in the past) also had bugs that caused the lifetime extension to not be correctly implemented, so that effectively the code would again have undefined behavior on them.

Instead use your original approach with named variables or just put the objects directly in the array using a `std::variant`:

```
std::variant<Generate,Scan> App::commands[] {Generate(), Scan()};
```

---

> even better, get rid of App.cpp and define commands directly in App.hpp

That's a separate issue and easy in C++17 and later: You just have to put `inline` before/after `static` and then it will be possible to initialize the static data member in-class the same way it would work outside of it.